# Select siblings between two nodes

Tags: python, html, xpath

I have to gather all category names along with all divs under them, having class starting with 'config-entry'.

```
<h2>category 1</h2>
<div class='clear10'></div>
<div class='config-entry selected-block'>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<h2>category 2</h2>
<div class='clear10'></div>
<div class='config-entry selected-block'>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<h2>category 3</h2>
<div class='clear10'></div>
<div class='config-entry selected-block'>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<h2>category 4</h2>
<div class='clear10'></div>
<div class='config-entry selected-block'>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
```

I am using the xpath `//h2[1]/following-sibling::h2[1]/preceding-sibling::div[starts-with(@class,'config-entry')]` like:

```
categories = root.xpath("//h2")
for i in xrange(len(categories)):
   print "----%s----" % categories[i].text
   contents = root.xpath("//h2[1]/following-sibling::h2[1]/preceding-sibling::div[starts-with(@class,'config-entry')]")
   print len(contents)
```

This code works good only for category 1. Selects all divs in between category 1 and 2, but screws up later on. I have played around with `h2[1]`, changing it to 0,2,3 but nothing concrete. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a union of the `h2` tags and the `div` tags, which will return them in document order and then when you process them, each div "belongs" to the last `h2` you saw.

E.g.

```
'//h2|//div[contains(@class,"config-entry")]'
```

Working example:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.HTML("""
<html>
<h2>category 1</h2>
<div class='clear10'></div>
<div class='config-entry selected-block'>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<h2>category 2</h2>
<div class='clear10'></div>
<div class='config-entry selected-block'>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<h2>category 3</h2>
<div class='clear10'></div>
<div class='config-entry selected-block'>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<h2>category 4</h2>
<div class='clear10'></div>
<div class='config-entry selected-block'>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
<div class='config-entry '>...</div>
</html>""")

category = None
for ele in doc.xpath('//h2|//div[contains(@class,"config-entry")]'):
  if ele.tag == 'h2':
    category = str(ele.text)
  else:
    if category:
      print "%s: %s, %r" % (category,ele.tag,ele.attrib)
```

Yielding:

```
category 1: div, {'class': 'config-entry selected-block'}
category 1: div, {'class': 'config-entry '}
category 1: div, {'class': 'config-entry '}
category 1: div, {'class': 'config-entry '}
category 2: div, {'class': 'config-entry selected-block'}
category 2: div, {'class': 'config-entry '}
category 2: div, {'class': 'config-entry '}
category 2: div, {'class': 'config-entry '}
category 2: div, {'class': 'config-entry '}
category 3: div, {'class': 'config-entry selected-block'}
category 3: div, {'class': 'config-entry '}
category 4: div, {'class': 'config-entry selected-block'}
category 4: div, {'class': 'config-entry '}
category 4: div, {'class': 'config-entry '}
category 4: div, {'class': 'config-entry '}
```